# RxJava2 concat operator doesn't return appropriate sequence

Tags: android, rx-java

When I make a request to the network, if an error occurs, then I will return data from the cache and the error. But sometimes I don’t get data from the cache, but I get only an error. The first time I launch the application, I always get only an error. If I call the getDashboard method once or several times, then everything is fine.
Here is a piece of code.

```
.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                        return Observable.concat(Observable.just(fromCache), Observable.error(throwable));
                    });
```

Full code here

https://gist.github.com/githubgist123/7e027675bb4db07fef606e23f39f8a96

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the way you're doing your caching is wrong in my opinion. If you request twice consecutively and the cache is empty you'll end up with two network requests running and racing each other to write to the cache. You don't want that.

What you need is:

```
Observable.concat(
                cache(),
                network().share().doOnNext(setCache(...)).onErrorReturn(...)
                .first()
)
```

You might think of `synchronized` your cache too or make it thread-safe by using the proper data structure.